# How to 'get' an element only generated for 3 seconds via javascript?

Tags: javascript

My problem basically is that i want to click on a `<button>` that appears inside a `<div>` that is available only for 3 seconds...
The `<div>` has `display:none`, so i can make it appear whenever i want, but the `<button>` is generated by an other js file that i don't have access to. I can not change the original js file (to give me more time, for example) because i'm only interacting with the page using a userscript! (not my own page)

I tried so far locating inside the js code the id or the class of the button generated, but the js is minified... so no luck...
I tried also using the temporary class that is generated during those 3 seconds for that button and click on it... by doing a screenshot typing the class manually and then running a little code in the console during those 3 seconds to click on it... and no luck...

By now i think the problem is my approach to the situation, so i didn't write any code here...
Please give me your thoughts about this...

Comment: Please throw down a codepen, or jsfiddle or something with code that we can use to help you with your problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can add [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) if you want to react to changes in DOM (*in your case to parent element*).

*Without any code it's hard to provide better answer.*

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/2FCvG/)

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var target = document.getElementById("hiddenElement"),
        observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
                console.log(value.type);
                console.dir(value.addedNodes); // return node list
                console.dir(value.removedNodes);
                // put here your logic
            });
        });

    observer.observe(target, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
        characterData: true,
        characterDataOldValue: true
    });    
}());

(function () {
    "use strict";


    var newEle = document.createElement("input"),
        hiddenElement = document.getElementById("hiddenElement");

    newEle.type = "button";
    newEle.value = "click";
    newEle.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        alert("Generated only for 3 second");
    });

    hiddenElement.appendChild(newEle);
    hiddenElement.style.display = "block";

    setTimeout(function() {
        hiddenElement.style.display = "none";
        hiddenElement.removeChild(newEle);
    }, 3000);    
}());
```

Comment: +1 I never knew such a thing existed. As always, IE support is less than stellar http://caniuse.com/mutationobserver

Comment: @WalterStabosz You can use [Mutation events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974346(v=vs.85).aspx) if you want support **IE 9** or **IE 10**, but it's deprecated in favor of [Mutation Observer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn254985(v=vs.85).aspx) in DOM4.

Answer (score 0):

Throw your button detection code inside a [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) that fires often enough that it will fire while the button is present:

```
// note: this is just pseudocode
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    // look for button
    if(buttonFound) {
        clickButton();
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 300);
```